# Android resources getting string names "dynamicaly"

Tags: android, string, android-resources

I have 2 activities, one with buttons which have ID's. Depending on which button you click, an ID is passed to a second activity through it's intent. I then in that second activity want to retrieve string values based on the id of that button. I had named my string values as followed:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">DataApp</string>
    <string name="info_title_zalm">Zalm</string>
    <string name="info_weight_zalm">1kg</string>
    <string name="info_origin_zalm">Atlantische Oceaan</string>
    <string name="info_title_haai">Haai</string>
    <string name="info_weight_haai">200kg</string>
    <string name="info_origin_haai">Atlantische Oceaan, zoet water uitzonderingen</string>
</resources>
```

So the string have a shared start of the name, for example info_title_zalm and info_title_haai. When clicking the haai button a "haai" string is passed to the second activity, where I was planning to do something such as "info_title_" + string to get the corresponding string. But because of needing to retrieve it as R.string.info_title_haai this doesn't work.

Is such a thing possible in Android?

Using Android Studio, building for Jellybean and above.

Comment: You can pass the `int` id (R.string.info_title_haai) instead of the value. Thus the second activity can obtain the value by `getString(extraID)`

Comment: oh wait. do you want to know the string name? For what?

Comment: but how do I build R.string.info_title_haai when it needs to depend on what button is pressed? I want to make it so that pressing the button decides which suffix is added and which strings appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this:

```
int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("info_title_" + string, "string", getPackageName());
String s = getString(resId);
```

[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) you have more info

Answer (score 2):

You can use a some kind of wrapper method like this (untested):

```
private String getStringResourceByName(String myResourceName) {
    String packageName = getPackageName();
    int resId = getResources()
            .getIdentifier(myResourceName, "string", packageName);
    if (resId == 0) {
        return myResourceName;
    } else {
        return getString(resId);
    }
}
```

Which will get values depending on matches to `myResourceName` - Then you can pass in whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have two options, you could pass the ID's of all the resources you need to via the intent.

If this table will grow larger, I think you're better off by packing a small database with your application.

Comment: You are right in that I would probably have to work with a small db if this would be larger, but for the time being I am just testing a concept with small amounts.